# CodeIgniter keeps redirecting to the same controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a strange problem. I was building my web application which will include dashboard,
login page, profile page etc. All in the sudden my app got stuck on that same controller no matter
what links I'll press.

I've tried to change

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

to

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'ORIG_PATH_INFO';
```

but it's only changing the actual URL in the address bar, nothing else.
I've also commented all the `redirect()` functions from my methods without luck.

Does anyone else ever had this type of problem?

Comment: DBCooper - you've got a million bucks; I wouldn't even care about CodeIgniter!

Answer (score 1):

Check your config route file:

> config/routes.php

If you use: `$route['(:any)'] = "primary/$1";` all the request will sent to the primary controller.

Comment: I don't have that particular route config, but I realized that If I change the $route['default_controller'], it will always use that controller, how can I overwrite this?